# How do I update the value of an object property inside of an array in React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I cannot seem to find an answer on here that is relevant to this scenario.

I have my state in my React component:

```
this.state = {
    clubs: [
       {
           teamId: null,
           teamName: null,
           teamCrest: null,
           gamesPlayed: []
        }
    ]
}
```

I receive some data through API request and I update only some of the state, like this:

```
this.setState((currentState) => {
    return {
        clubs: currentState.clubs.concat([{
            teamId: team.id,
            teamName: team.shortName,
            teamCrest: team.crestUrl
        }]),
    }
});
```

Later on I want to modify the state value of one of the properties values - the gamesPlayed value.

How do I go about doing this?
If I apply the same method as above it just adds extra objects in to the array, I can't seem to target that specific objects property.
I am aiming to maintain the objects in the clubs array, but modify the gamesPlayed property.

Essentially I want to do something like:

```
clubs: currentState.clubs[ index ].gamesPlayed = 'something';
```

But this doesn't work and I am not sure why.

Comment: Should the `teamId` be unique throughout the array?

Comment: Yes, id, name and crest are being pulled from json data.

Answer (score 0):

Cus you are using `concat()` function which add new item in array.

You can use **findIndex** to find the index in the array of the objects and replace it as required:

**Solution:**

```
 this.setState((currentState) => {
    var foundIndex = currentState.clubs.findIndex(x => x.id == team.id);
    currentState.clubs[foundIndex] = team;

    return clubs: currentState.clubs
});
```

Comment: Thank you Nikola, but team.id will not register the same as x.id.
Team.id is a number being pulled from an API request.

Comment: You're welcome. try with shortName or with crestUrl.  Like this: findIndex(x => x.shortName  == team.shortName);

Comment: You're modifying the `currentState`, which is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I would change how your state is structured. As `teamId` is unique in the array, I would change it to an object.

```
clubs = {
  teamId: {
    teamName,
    teamCrest,
    gamesPlayed
  }
}
```

You can then update your state like this:

```
addClub(team) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      clubs: {
        [team.id]: {
          teamName: team.shortName,
          teamCrest: teamCrestUrl
        },
        ...prevState.clubs
      }
    }));
  }

  updateClub(teamId, gamesPlayed) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      clubs: {
        [teamId]: {
          ...prevState.clubs[teamId],
          gamesPlayed: gamesPlayed
        },
        ...prevState.clubs
      }
    }));
  }
```

This avoids having to `find` through the array for the team. You can just select it from the object.

You can convert it back into an array as needed, like this:

```
Object.keys(clubs).map(key => ({
  teamId: key,
  ...teams[key]
  }))
```

Answer (score -1):

The way I approach this is `JSON.parse` && `JSON.stringify` to make a deep copy of the part of state I want to change, make the changes with that copy and update the state from there.

The only drawback from using `JSON` is that you do not copy functions and references, keep that in mind.

For your example, to modify the `gamesPlayed` property:

```
let newClubs = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.clubs))

newClubs.find(x => x.id === team.id).gamesPlayed.concat([gamesPlayedData])

this.setState({clubs: newClubs})
```

I am assuming you want to append new `gamesPlayedData` each time from your API where you are given a `team.id` along with that data.

Comment: 1) Using `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` is not necessary, as we don't need a `deep` copy. These are two expensive operations.
2) `concat` does not alter the array, but returns the newly concatenated one instead - which you don't save into a variable or use otherwise

Comment: @LorenzHenk appreciate the comment and insight